# Highest velocity impact between a spacecraft and a solar system body? What about for a dedicated impactor (spacecraft component)?

Tags: history, planetary-science, solar-system, impact, dart

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34066/12102) I mention the proposed impact of DART:

- [Double Asteroid Redirection Test (DART) Mission](https://www.nasa.gov/planetarydefense/dart)
- [Double Asteroid Redirection Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Asteroid_Redirection_Test)
- [The Double Asteroid Redirection Test (DART) Element of the Asteroid Impact and Deflection Assessment (AIDA) Mission](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2017/pdf/1510.pdf)

DART's impact velocity would be about 6 km/s on a body so small that the momentum transfer is hoped to measurably change its orbit around a companion asteroid.

I wondered about impacts used for other reasons, so I'd like to ask:

1. What's the highest velocity impact between a spacecraft and a solar system body?
2. What about for a dedicated impactor (spacecraft component)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that Deep Impact was the highest velocity impact, but I think it was.  What's crazy is that it wasn't even a head-on collision.  JPL just put the impactor out in front of Tempel-1 and let the comet hit it.

In the interest of a complete answer that can be amended with further information here's a list of known impactors, and their impact velocities:

- [Deep Impact](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/press_kits/deep-impact-encounter.pdf) ~10.3 km/s -- dedicated impactor (see page 13)
- [Messenger](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-completes-messenger-mission-with-expected-impact-on-mercurys-surface)   ~ 3.8 km/s -- impacted on decomissioning
- [LCROSS](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LCROSS/searchforwater/LCROSS_impact.html)      ~ 2.5 km/s -- dedicated impactor (Centaur upper stage)
- [Apollo SIVBs](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/lunar/apollo_impact.html) ~ 1.6-2.6 km/s  -- impacted for debris mitigation

Comment: Hey this is great! Can I ask you to indicate somehow which are dedicated impactors and which are spacecraft? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't include spacecraft that de-orbited into the gas giants, since I figured you were only asking about impacts to solid bodies. I also left out Mars Climate Observer (the units crash) since it is believed to have burned up in the atmosphere.

Comment: Schiaparelli isn't even in the running -- it crashed into Mars at about 0.15 km/s.  If anyone was wondering.