# Fastest Manmade Object

Tags: launch, velocity

I remember reading somewhere that during the cold war, a nuclear weapon was placed underground with a manhole cover on-top and then detonated. I'm pretty sure the manhole cover then went orbital however I can't remember any more details. Was this the fastest object launched from earth? What allowed it to reach such speeds? If not, what was?

**Question:**

- What is the fastest manmade object to ever leave the surface? What was its speed? What was the story behind the event?

Comment: Other references to the supposed manhole cover incident https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28026/what-is-the-largest-delta-v-ever-produced-in-space-from-mechanically-stored-ener/28036#28036 https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/what-was-the-first-man-made-object-to-leave-our-solar-system/8115#8115

Comment: You might want to look up Voyager 1 and 2...

Comment: Clarification: Do you want "The object that had the highest earth departure speed", "Of all known objects, the one that will be the furthest from Earth, in say, 10,000 years,"  "The object that has achieved the highest Earth-relative velocity", as the answer to each of those is a different object.

Comment: Different but related: [What is the fastest can we or have ever traveled in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28421/12102) (hint: look for spacecraft close to the Sun, probably needs or will soon need an updated answer) For the fastest ballistic launch look for a really really big cannon! [this potentially crazy thing probably won't be launched at 2000 m/s in the near future](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33911/12102)

Comment: I'm sure I have a post about a cannon-launched ballistic device currently under development somewhere; I think they are looking at applications both pointing up towards space, and down for some kind of prospecting or geoengineering applications, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I'll take a look at all the posts. @notovny I was asking departure speed, while the others are valuable questions in their own right, I believe they'd be too much to be in the same question.

Comment: so I've just asked [Looking for a ballistic projectile technology development company I'd read about a few years(?) ago.](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52272/12102)

Comment: See this: https://www.zmescience.com/science/news-science/fastest-manmade-object-manhole-cover-nuclea-test/

Comment: If I may go laterally,  there have been millions of man-made photons which launched, duh, at the speed of light.  Even if we restrict ourselves to particles with rest mass, we've got pretty close to $c$

Comment: @CarlWitthoft since neutrinos have mass and can be considered matter, they might serve as a better example (bombs, reactors, etc.)